# How exactly do you set these post holders into concrete?

Tags: concrete, deck, post

How should you set these bases into concrete?

Do you push them all the way down? Or should you leave a gap underneath? If you leave a gap, how big a gap should you leave? It has drain holes on the bottom, which makes me think it needs to be off the concrete, but then you have the full weight of you 6x6 post on that one piece of steel.

What's the proper/best way to set this into concrete?

[image]

Comment: Are we talking about inserting the re-bar end in a hole in cured concrete or into the top of a just-poured concrete surface?

Comment: Are you using it as a fence post base?

Comment: Most of those questions depend on your use case. Please revise the question to describe your project in appropriate detail. Also, the manufacturer has almost certainly provided a spec sheet that outlines usage and limitations.

Comment: You have more questions than this has answers but here you go https://peakproducts-canada.s3.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com/PostHolder_InstalInstr_V3.pdf

Answer (score 2):

That base goes into a hole drilled into a concrete slab, and is then attached with epoxy. The base of the bracket bears on the cured slab. Follow the epoxy manufacturer's instructions regarding hole clearance and cleaning procedure.

Comment: Usually the base goes into a just-poured slab or foundation pad.  No need for epoxy in that situation.

Comment: A wet-set post anchor has a different shape. This is not for wet concrete.

Comment: https://aylesbury-gates.co.uk/shop/fencing-posts/fencing-accessories/concrete-in-u-post-support-bracket/ which is almost identical, is described as "concrete in".

Comment: After doing a little more research on the Simpson website, it is marketed in some non-US countries as both for certain limited structural applications. I will fix or delete my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your application. If it is inside and dry you can just push it all the way down. to prevent rot outside (or basement) I would leave a 1/4 inch (5mm) gap to allow the wood to dry out in case water collects under it. I assume you mean newly poured concrete. The steel is strong enough either way.

Answer (score 0):

And there are other models, such as this one from [Simpson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01CF07G5Y). It needs an additional 5/8 inch bolt epoxied into a hole in the concrete. Once you affixed the base, you can add the stand-off cover and set the post on it.